# rails update checkbox value with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I'm trying to update a rails form with ajax but I don't know how.

What i know about ajax in rails is: that i need to set up remote:true in the form and then i have to create a file called the same but instead of *.html.erb i do *.js.erb.

Now I'm using a form in the show.html.erb which calls the method edit.html.erb ... Do i have to write the js code into edit.js.erb or show.js.erb?

I got checkboxes and they should be updated everytime i click on them.

Can someone point me in the right direction and provide some jquery code? I have to no idea how to solve that problem.

Thanks in advance

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @order, remote:true do |g| %>
<%= g.label "recieve sms?" %>
<%= g.check_box :send_sms %>
<%= g.label "recieve email?" %>
<%= g.check_box :send_email %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
    if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
        format.js { render json: @order, status: "200" }
    else
        format.js { render json: @order, status: "400" }
    end
end
end
```

somekind of of try:

```
$.ajax('/orders/613', {
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('works !');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well you don't have a submit button so I'm guessing you just want an ajax request per click.  In that case you don't need to add `remote: true` because you aren't actually "submitting" the form.

You DO need to make your ajax request bound to the form.  By default, on a form_for for an object which already exists, the class name that is generated (this is specific to the form_for helper, if you're using simple_form it's different) is called `edit_` in your case `edit_order`  so you can bind your ajax request to that class.

Also I just find it easier to set the URL of where it's posting to in the erb.

So the steps to take are:

Step 1 - Add the submit url to a js variable

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.ordersURL = '<%= order_path(@order.id) %>';
<% end %>
```

Step 2 - Set your ajax request to utilize the url, set it to javscript so your update action knows which format to render, set the request type to PUT, and create the data hash.  (this is coffee script but feel free to convert to js) -- this file would be app_name/app/javascripts/order.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".edit_order").on "change", ->
    url = ordersURL
    $.ajax
      url: url
      type: "PUT"
      dataType: "script"
      data:
        order:
          receive_sms: $("input[name='order[send_sms]']").is(':checked')
          receive_email: $("input[name='order[send_email]']").is(':checked')
```

Then you can do whatever you want in your update action.  None of this requires a js.erb file unless you want something on the screen to change after the check or uncheck.